# how to paste something in textbox without overwriting

Tags: c#

hi i created a little app for my business. Now i have a little problem. 
I want to paste one code of textbox2 to textbox4 without erasing previous data of textbox4..

I tried these codes but it doesn't work

for copy==>

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(textBox2.Text);
    }
```

for paste ===>

```
 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox4.Text =Clipboard.GetText()+Environment.NewLine;
    }
```

this paste code is overwriting. I want a method for paste button to keep previous data when pasting new data..

Help me plz

Comment: You're overwriting the text instead of appending. Just use `textBox4.Text += Clipboard.GetText();` to append the text instead.

Answer (score 8):

Because you're setting the value of the text:

```
textBox4.Text = ...
```

If you only want to *append* the value, use the `+=` operator:

```
textBox4.Text += ...
```

Or, more explicitly:

```
textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text + ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For pasting the new value without removing the old text, you can do it like below in your `button6` click event :

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox4.Text += Clipboard.GetText() + Environment.NewLine;
}
```